# Parsing Out Code Between Comment Blocks PHP

Tags: php, code-generation, phpdoc

Lets say I have the following piece of start in a PHP file:

```
/**
 * @SomethingStart
 */
protected static $var1 = '1';
protected static $var2 = '2';
protected static $var3 = '3';
/**
 * @SomethingEnd
 */
```

I am trying to figure out how I can first parse out the content between the comments with @SomethingStart and @SomethingEnd (not including the comment and then secondly, how I can replace the content between those two tags.

Comment: You could use `preg_replace_all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the contents of the file with the function:

```
file
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

That returns an array of lines. Then you can use foreach, and match the line content with

```
$switch = false; 
$lines = file('filepath');
$string = '';
foreach($lines as $k => $v)
{
    if(preg_match('/@(.*)End$/'. $v))
    {
        $switch = false;
        break;
    }
    if($switch == true)
    {
        // do replacements, or anything you want with the following lines
        // or add, or remove, even if you might have some problems with it
        // for this you might not consider using foreach, instead you might
        // try array_walk
    }
    if(preg_match('/@(.*)Start$/', $v))
    {
        $switch = true;
    }


    $string .= $v;
}

echo $string;
```

For array_walk, read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Try it.

Comment: Maybe the preg_match of the start and end lines should be before actual processing of the lines to not to accidentaly edit them out.

Comment: I have edited my answer, the test for end must be before, and the one for start at the end, in the foreach logic, when it will encounter a stop command it will break, and on the other side only in the step that follows the start command will start modifying things.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I needed (with minor tweaks for my particular case)